# Disable type hints in Intellij for type aliases?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

After upgrading to Intellij Idea 2021.2 I get type hints for type aliases like this:

[image]

I want to hide `/* = kotlin.String */` but I fail to find where in the preferences I can do this. I've tried to disable *all* type hints in "Inlay Hints" (not just "Parameter hints" that are shown in the screenshot below) but it doesn't make any difference:

[image]

Does anyone know how to disable type hints for type aliases in Kotlin using Intellij 2021.2?

Comment: Can you file an issue, please - https://kotl.in/issue?

Comment: Created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48231

Answer (score 0):

How about Preferences \ Editor \ Inlay Hints \ Kotlin ?

[image]

Or alternatively, `<SHIFT> <SHIFT>` and search for Parameter Hints